# Can I #define QStringLiterals in header files?

Tags: c++, qt

It looks like C++ compilers allow me to `#define` QStringLiterals within C++ header files. Something like:

```
// foo.h
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

#define BAR QStringLiteral("bar")

#endif
```

The goal is to use (copy) `BAR` in different .cpp files that includes `foo.h`, so that I can avoid to type multiple times `QStringLiteral("bar")`.

But:

- Is it safe? (I heard QStringLiteral can lead to crashes)
- Is it efficient? (i.e. is the string allocated only once?)

Comment: Just *defining* a macro doesn't really do anything, and wont affect any code the compiler sees. It's all how you *use* the macro.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: the goal is to use `BAR` in different .cpp files that includes `foo.h`

Comment: define just does textual replacement, thus in principle you can define anything you want. Is it safe? No. Macros should be avoided whenever possible and I am sure, you can get what you want in a different way much nicer and safer. What do you actually want to achieve? What is the purpose of this `#define`  ?

Comment: @tobi303: I don't want to type `QStringLiteral("bar")` in multiple locations of my codebase.

Comment: " is the string allocated only once?" no, each time you use the macro a new instance gets created. Using the macro is equivalent to writing `QStringLiteral("bar")` at each occurence of `BAR`

Comment: lazyness of typing is the main cause of obfuscated and terrible to maintain code. Just dont do it and your life will be easier.

Comment: I feel I should comment my own comment... lazyness of typing actually can also be the main cause of clear and easy to maintain code as well. The problem is just that imho macros are the wrong tool if you aim for less typing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't do that.

Regarding your questions:

- Is it safe? (I heard QStringLiteral can lead to crashes)

The question is *why* QStringLiteral may crash, and the answer has to do with library and plugin unloading. QStringLiteral creates a QString which references a payload (QString's own data and the actual string) that is static. If this QString created in library A, passed to library B, and then library A is unloaded, B is left with a dangerous dangling pointer. There's nothing Qt can do here.

- Is it efficient? (i.e. is the string allocated only once?)

Not at all:

1. You end up with the string literal data appearing everywhere you use it. That can explode data size, or put more pressure on the linker to merge the identical string literal data across the multiple TUs.
2. Since QStringLiteral expands to a lambda-expression (... given decent compilers), you put pressure on the compiler to parse and generate code for the lambda expression every time the macro appears
3. Since each lambda must convey an object of an unique type, multiple macro expansion -- even in the same TU -- cannot be easily merged by the compiler. Only recently optimizers started to fold identical binary code.

Solution: write an out of line function:

```
// foo.h
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

QString bar();

#endif
```

And

```
// foo.cpp
#include "foo.h"
QString bar() {
    return QStringLiteral("bar");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Can I #define QStringLiterals in header files?

You can, but you shouldn't, as explained in other answer(s).

Another approach is to use global string constants, with a distinguishing prefix to avoid global namespace pollution. You could also put them into a namespace:

```
// bar.h
#pragma once
#include <QString>

extern const QString kBar; // approach 1
namespace K {
  extern const QString bar; // approach 2
}

// bar.cpp
#include "bar.h"

const QString kBar { QStringLiteral("bar"); } 
const QString K::bar { QStringLiteral("bar"); }

// main.cpp
#include "bar.h"
int main() {
  qDebug() << kBar << K::bar;
}
```

If you're worried about initialization order, then simply presume that the values are undefined before you enter `main()`; have `main()` explicitly instantiate everything that depends on these constants. You should probably code that way anyway, so that shouldn't be a problem in practice.